# Merging javascript nested array of objects with parent objects in the following form in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an object with one of the property storing array of objects I wanted to create new object in the following form,

```
{
    customerEmailID: 'customer@test.com',
    devices: [
        {
            deviceName: 'Desktop',
            deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9861',
        },
        {
            deviceName: 'Mobile',
            deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9862',
        },
        {
            deviceName: 'Laptop',
            deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9863',
        }
    ]

}
```

Expected output is,

```
{
    customerEmailID: 'customer@test.com',
    deviceName1: 'Desktop',
    deviceType1: 'ZENW42NLPC9861',
    deviceName2: 'Mobile',
    deviceType2: 'ZENW42NLPC9862',
    deviceName3: 'Laptop',
    deviceType3: 'ZENW42NLPC9863',
}
```

I wanted to create a unique column name after merge with respective parent properties.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce for create new structure:

```js
const data = {
    customerEmailID: 'customer@test.com',
    devices: [
        {
            deviceName: 'Desktop',
            deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9861',
        },
        {
            deviceName: 'Mobile',
            deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9862',
        },
        {
            deviceName: 'Laptop',
            deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9863',
        }
    ]
}

const newData = data.devices.reduce((acc, rec, index) => {
  return {...acc, [`deviceName${index+1}`]: rec.deviceName, [`deviceType${index+1}`]: rec.deviceType}
}, { customerEmailID: data.customerEmailID })


console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `loop` through array with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and add `properties` as shown below.

```js
let obj = {
  customerEmailID: 'customer@test.com',
  devices: [{
      deviceName: 'Desktop',
      deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9861',
    },
    {
      deviceName: 'Mobile',
      deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9862',
    },
    {
      deviceName: 'Laptop',
      deviceType: 'ZENW42NLPC9863',
    }
  ]
};

let result = {
  customerEmailID: obj.customerEmailID
};

obj.devices.forEach((x, i) => {
  result["deviceName" + (i + 1).toString()] = x.deviceName;
  result["deviceType" + (i + 1).toString()] = x.deviceType;
});

console.log(result);
```